# Dragging and drawing an arrow from one node to another in GridPane in JavaFX?

Tags: graphics, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on a JavaFX application in which I have a `GridPane`. The `GridPane` consists of `Panes`. I intend to mouse click on any `Pane` from the `GridPane` and start drawing an arrow using `CubicCurve`. Later, I would release mouse when the intended `Pane` is reached. Hence, I want to draw an arrow between given two GridPane cells/nodes using `CubicCurve`. My UI looks like following:

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWgfJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWgfJ.png

Could anyone please suggest me how I could draw a directed arrow, for instance, from cell(2,2) to cell(4,4). I am not able to find easiest way (less code) to do it.